# keep the shell open after running migration task in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell, amazon-ecs

I have some containers running in aws ecs (ec2 based) all containers are running ruby on rails applicatin and we are using ecs-exec to connect with them. I need to run the migration task and need to keep the shell open after running that task. Any idea what I need to add after the migration command to do this?

The command I am using to run the migration task is `rake db:migrate`.

```
Will something like work rake db:migrate exec $SHELL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep shell open after running ruby gemstone migration and after party tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254564/keep-shell-open-after-running-ruby-gemstone-migration-and-after-party-tasks)

Comment: @eugen no answer on your mentioned link.